# jquery move element to last child position

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Let's say I have a `<div>` that contains some random elements, but there is one element I've created with this unique selector : `$('.myUniqueElement')`. I want to use `.insertAfter()` to move this element at last child position in my `<div>` is that possible ? what is the solution ?

This is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/silverlight/RmB5K/3/ is this OK ??

```js
$('#b').on('click',function(){
    $('.myUniqueElement').insertAfter($('.p :last-child'))
});
```

```css
.myUniqueElement{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='p'>
    <div class='myUniqueElement'>unique</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
</div>
<input type='button' id='b' value='Do'/>
```

Comment: Post your HTML snippet...

Comment: this is my solution, is this ok? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/silverlight/RmB5K/3/)

Comment: checkout my answer with fiddle

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, your solution and the one by @vikasdevde are both valid (they work!).

Comment: I want to shrink my codes i don't want to create a clone and delete last one, do you know what `.insertAfter()` exactly doing when it moves an element ?

Comment: I never read the jQuery source code, so I don't know the details... but I think that elements are never cloned unless you explicitly create a copy (clone).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try

```
var mydiv = $('my-div-selector');
mydiv.find('.myUniqueElement').appendTo(mydiv)
```

or simple

```
$('my-div').append($('.myUniqueElement'))
```

Answer (score 14):

There is no need to use `.insertAfter`.  You should also *not* use `.clone` as it'll remove any attached data or events, unless you use `.clone(true)`.

Simply use `.appendTo` to add the target element to the `div` and it'll get detached from its original position and added as the last child of the `div`:

```
$('.myUniqueElement').appendTo('#my-div');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution and I think this is the best way I can use `.insertAfter()`:

HTML:

```
<div class='p'>
    <div class='myUniqueElement'>unique</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
</div>
<input type='button' id='b' value='Do'/>
```

jquery:

```
$('#b').on('click',function(){
    $('.myUniqueElement').insertAfter($('.p :last-child'))
});
```

The point is [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)
and this is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/silverlight/RmB5K/3/

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to call $ more than once, just move the element to the end of its parent:

```
var myEl = $('.my-el-selector');
myEl.appendTo(myEl.parent());
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to use `insertAfter()`, you must know the element after which you want to move your element to. And as you said you have random elements, and of course you don't know the current last element, so here what you can do.

Clone your element that you want to move and append it to parent element.

The jQuery code looks like this:

```
$clone_elem = $('.myUniqueElement').clone();
$('.myUniqueElement').remove();
$('div').append($clone_elem);
```

Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vikasdevde/RmB5K/2/)

Comment: Good, you got better solution, +1 for you.

Comment: `.clone` should only be used if you actually want to copy an element.  _Moving_ elements is trivially done without copying them.

Answer (score -1):

Vikas is right. However, probably this one is an improved version of it since the original element is removed, not its clone....

```
    $elem = $('.myUniqueElement')
    $('div').append($elem.clone());
    $elem.remove();
```