# Change JS Show/hide to reorder

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some perfectly working javascript here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('#filterText').on('change', function() {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();
  console.log(currentVal)

  $(".group-container").show();
  if (currentVal == 'popularity') {
  $('.group-container input[name="topseller"]').each(function (index, value){
  if($(this).val() == "0"){
        $(this).parent('.group-container').hide();
        //console.log(currentVal)
    }
    });
  } else if (currentVal == 'recently_ordered') {
    $('.group-container input[name="reorder"]').each(function (index, value){

        if($(this).val() == "0"){
                $(this).parent('.group-container').hide();
                // console.log(currentVal)
            }
      });
  }
});
});

</script>
```

However, I'd like to change one thing. Currently, it checks the value of the select box and a hidden input name, and it then hides the divs containing the inputs with value of 0 and shows the ones with value of 1.

I want to just slightly refactor this to, rather than hide the div, just reorder them and basically show the divs that have input value of 1 first and the value of 0 last. SO no hide/show but rather just give the one's with value of 1 priority at top of the page. I'm thinking this should be a very minor change in my show/hide script, but don't know exactly how I should go about it.

UPDATE with HTML

```
<div>
   <span style="color:#fff;"><strong>Sort by:</strong></span>
        <select id="filterText" class="uk-text-muted" style="margin-top:10px; width:33%; height:30px; font-size: 16px;" >
        <option id="allitems" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" selected data-default value="" selected data-default>All Items</option>
                                      file
        <option id="recent" class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" value="recently_ordered">Recently Ordered </option>
       </select>
    </div>

@foreach ($orderFormData->pgroups as $pgroup)
<div class="group-container">
        <!-- <input type='hidden' name='search' value='{{ x.search }}' > -->
        <input type="hidden" name="topseller" value="{{$pgroup->topseller}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="reorder" value="{{$pgroup->reorder}}"/>
```

Comment: Could you post your html?

Comment: look into `.prepend` and `.append` instead of show/hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try $(this).append($('.group-container'))
instead of $(this).parent('.group-container').hide();

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427255/jquery-move-element-to-last-child-position) for more details.

Comment: I've tried this but it just seems to hide all group-container divs

Comment: you can reorder them by [flex order](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp)